# Why a speciffic CSS class in not applied?

Tags: css, django, bootstrap-4

I have recently started learning Django framework with Python. I've been doing a course on YouTube. Unfortunately, one of the steps did not go as on the course.

The CSS and JS features does not apply to my page. Do you have some suggestions to make it apply to my page? I was using the starter template.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    {% if title %}
        <title>Django Blog - {{ title }}</title>
    {% else %}
        <title>Django blog</title>
    {% endif %}
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The issue isn't replicated with the code you provided.

Comment: It's actually working, You need to know which version of bs you're working with because classes names change over versions

Comment: I have checked and in both versions, 4.0 and 4.3 the "container" class exists. So that is probably not the case,

Answer (score 0):

I can see you're using Bootstrap CDN. Maybe when the tutorial was recorded, Bootstrap had a different version (for example, v3.0). However, currently you will get the latest version (v4.3.1) from their website. In that case, some styles will not work. For example, bootstrap3 had `img-circle`, `pull-right` classes which have been now changed into `rounded-circle`, `float-right` classes respectively in the latest version.

If you want to follow along, I recommend you take note of the version that's being used in the tutorial and **use that particular version** in your project. Another option would be a simple google search to see if the CSS class exists in the latest version. If not, they have probably just renamed the class and you should use the new class names.

Comment: Actually, I have tried to paste the code from the movie and it did not work out either. Im currently websurfing for the 4.3.1 boostrap name changes, but cannot find anything. The guy from video uses 4.0.0.

Comment: I have checked and in both versions, 4.0 and 4.3 the "container" class exists. So that is probably not the case

Comment: Okay, I have done exactly the same steps as the tutor. Exactly the same bootstrap page with exactly the same version. Still not working. Any other tips?